# HTML: center image caption relative to image?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to write HTML to align an image caption *in the centre relative to the image*.

I'd like to align the *image and the caption together* to the left.

This should be true whatever the width of the containing element.

This is what I have so far:

```
[unknown containing element]
<div style="align: left; text-align:center;">
<img src="white.jpg" height="31px" width="200px" />
<span>Some caption text</span>
</div>
[/unknown]
```

But it's aligning the caption text centre relative to the containing element.

What do I need to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example page we can see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really mean relative to the image, make the caption element as wide as the image, then center the text. To be able to set a width on the caption element it needs to be a block element, so I changed it from  to :

```
<div style="align: left; text-align:center;">
    <img src="white.jpg" height="31px" width="200px" />
    <div class="caption">Some caption text</div>
</div>

.caption {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You might set the width with inline CSS if that is easier.

```
<div style="align: left; text-align:center;">
    <img src="white.jpg" height="31px" width="200px" />
    <div class="caption" style="width: 200px">Some caption text</div>
</div>

.caption {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Surprised there's no way to do it without specifying explicit widths, though.

Comment: There is, check the first comment of my answer.

Comment: I was using this in Markdown instead of html, and I am not sure why but the latter part starting with `.caption` was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the `<span>` act like a block element.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/szNvt/

Comment: Also i may have miss read your question the first time, maybe this is more what you require: [http://jsfiddle.net/szNvt/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/szNvt/1/)

Comment: Isn't span with display:block a div? :)

Comment: sure. What i was trying to do was use the users code. There may have been a specific reason they wanted it to be a span.

Comment: Yes it was just to point that out.. to also let the questioneer know it ;)

Comment: Hi @Alex, this is very close, thanks! But is there a way to float the image left, with the caption centered relative to the image?

Comment: Check my first comment is that what you require?

Answer (score 0):

#### Center image caption in image

```css
.container {padding:0.1em}  
.display-container {position:relative; width:50%}

.display-middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}

img {width: 100%;}
```

```html
    <div class="container">     
      <div class="display-container">   
      
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/10" />       
        <div class="display-middle">
          <p>strikee .. !</p>
        </div>
       
      </div>     
    </div>
```